# there are a widget like facebook chat/activities?

Tags: dojo

I need to create a content-pane that I can expand or minimize in the right-bottom column of my layout page/screen.

Are there something in dijit o dojox module component for realize that?

I need to insert this widget into z-index level upper that my CSS layout, and position in in bottom-right of my page.

When I click on the *expande*...the control show a content-pane that go to 100% height and 100px of weight like facebook activity/chat menu.

Tnx you so everyone for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tnx you I have develop the solution **TitleGroup** Dojo component...

tnx you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a box that expands onclick than you can use dojos AccordionContainer.

Here's the Link - http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/layout/AccordionContainer.html#dijit-layout-accordioncontainer

For your case you must set the z-index to 1000, that ensures thats it's definetly above all other css. By setting  data-dojo-props="region:'right'" you can set it to the right side of your browser.

Have a look : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/layout.html?highlight=region

Regards